# How do I find a command associated with an installed .deb file?

Tags: apt, package-management

Is there any way to see what commands were installed by a package?

I installed JetUML through a .deb file and the `apt install` command. It seems to have installed okay, but when I try to run `jetuml` as a command, I get `jetuml: command not found`. So how can I find what command I just installed?

When I run `apt list jetuml` I get `jetuml/now 3-1 amd64 [installed,local]`, and perhaps more importantly when I run `apt-cache show jetuml` I get:

```
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 87269
Maintainer: Unknown <Unknown>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3-1
Provides: jetuml
Depends: libasound2, libatk-bridge2.0-0, libatk1.0-0, libatspi2.0-0, libblkid1, libbsd0, libc6, libcairo-gobject2, libcairo2, libdatrie1, libdbus-1-3, libepoxy0, libexpat1, libffi6, libfontconfig1, libfreetype6, libgcrypt20, libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0, libgl1, libglib2.0-0, libglvnd0, libglx0, libgpg-error0, libgraphite2-3, libgtk-3-0, libgtk2.0-0, libharfbuzz0b, liblz4-1, liblzma5, libmount1, libpango-1.0-0, libpangocairo-1.0-0, libpangoft2-1.0-0, libpcre3, libpixman-1-0, libpng16-16, libselinux1, libsystemd0, libthai0, libuuid1, libwayland-client0, libwayland-cursor0, libwayland-egl1, libx11-6, libxau6, libxcb-render0, libxcb-shm0, libxcb1, libxcomposite1, libxcursor1, libxdamage1, libxdmcp6, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6, libxinerama1, libxkbcommon0, libxrandr2, libxrender1, libxtst6, zlib1g
Description: JetUML
Description-md5: 42461daef042532d9ee79b62511a038a
```

I thought that the `Provides: jetuml` line would mean that a `jetuml` command is added somewhere, but I'm clearly missing something.

Any help on understanding what's going on would be appreciated!

Comment: How certain are you that is a valid command in the context of the software you installed?  You ought to include in your question the details of each step you took when you installed the software

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by valid command? I think that's what I'm trying to find (what command launches the software I installed)? As for install, I did `sudo apt install ./filename.deb` and got what looks like a successful install message. I can add that to the question if you think it would be useful.

Comment: Try `dpkg-deb -c [filename.deb]`.

Comment: I'm on their github, I dont see a deb package. can you post a link to the deb file you used?

Comment: @EricPower I think the word Nmath wanted to use is "argument."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no connection between the package name and programs it installs. As an example, consider the package `procps`. It provides many tools:

```
~$ dpkg -L procps | grep /usr/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/free
/usr/bin/pgrep
/usr/bin/pmap
/usr/bin/pwdx
/usr/bin/skill
/usr/bin/slabtop
/usr/bin/tload
/usr/bin/top
/usr/bin/uptime
/usr/bin/vmstat
/usr/bin/w.procps
/usr/bin/watch
/usr/bin/pkill
/usr/bin/snice
```

...and none of them is called `procps`.

An even better example is the `coreutils` package. It's list of executables is too long to post here, but you are welcome to explore.

Consider also that a package doesn't have to install a program. It could be a theme or a bunch of wallpapers.

Comment: This got me to the right answer, so I'm going to accept it, thank you! I'll just note (for anyone here in the future) that I while I had previously looked at common /bin folders (eg. usr/bin) without any luck, the `dpkg -L jetuml` returned some other places to look. Specifically, it listed opt/jeturl as a directory, which contained the JetUML binary that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to answer this using an example from LibreOffice.

1. Learn the *path* to a command.

   ```
   $ which soffice
   /usr/bin/soffice
   ```
2. Learn which *package(s)* provide that path.

   ```
   $ dpkg -S /usr/bin/soffice
   libreoffice-common: /usr/bin/soffice
   ```
3. See what other *files* are provided by that package.

   ```
   $ dpkg -L libreoffice-common
   [over 3500 directories and files listed]
   ```

   Ouch, let's narrow that a bit by looking for strings that include `/bin`. That will get us to a manageable number of candidates. Some are applications, some are not. And, of course, maybe some executable are in a different directory entirely! So filter with care -- not everything is in /bin.

   ```
   $ dpkg -L libreoffice-common | grep /bin
   /usr/bin
   /usr/bin/loffice
   /usr/bin/lofromtemplate
   /usr/bin/unopkg
   /usr/share/libreoffice/bin
   /usr/share/libreoffice/bin/lo-xlate-lang
   /usr/bin/libreoffice
   /usr/bin/soffice
   ```

   Apt doesn't keep track of which files are applications, nor is there any rule that the package must have any application inside at all, nor is there any rule that any application must match the package name. There is no easy, certain, programmatic way for the last step of identifying applications from among the other files in the package.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but my issue was that I couldn't find the command (or any command) related to the package so step 1 gave me nothing.